# Bootstrap modal carousel first item slides too fast despite setting data-interval

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, carousel

In my webpage, there's a gallery of images and on click of those images a modal pops up in which there is a carousel of images (related to the image that was clicked).

I've used HTML, CSS, jQuery and Bootstrap 4.
Since there are multiple images in the gallery, I am adding data to the modal/carousel dynamically through jQuery arrays. I have set the carousel images' data-interval to be 4000, it works fine when the page is loaded for the first time ie. first image in the carousel also takes 4s to slide, but when I close this modal and click on another image in the gallery, the first image in its modal carousel slides too fast.

I think somehow what's happening is that for eg. in gallery there are 2 images: Tree and Flower.
When I click on Tree the modal pops up and first carousel image T1 takes 4s and second image T2 takes 2s and I close the modal. Then when I open Flower's modal the first carousel image F1 gets only 2s (because T2 took its 2s in previous version of carousel). I'm not sure if it makes sense or the carousel is always destroyed when the modal is closed.

What can I do to rectify it?

**EDIT**
The issue could be seen at: https://deepikauix.com/ak/portfolio.html
The sliding of first image is pretty random, sometimes it takes time to slide, sometimes it just slides really fast.

Comment: Can you please add minimal code to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: @Prince Hi, I was still working on localhost, therefore couldn't share the result, you can check it on https://deepikauix.com/ak/portfolio.html.
Click on the 'View' button to trigger the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code in the specified URL. I think you should delete the previous carousel from DOM as soon as user clicks on cancel icon.

Can you please check by making the below change.

```
$('#portfolioModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
    $('.carousel-inner').empty();
});
```

Comment: This removes the carousel all together, doesn't load the carousel at all when modal opened again. I tried using .carousel("dispose") also but that also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure .... I have updated the code, I hope you will be able to open the modal again with new code. Can you please check again ?

Comment: No difference :/

Comment: Problem is i am not able to run the hidden event in console. Is the event listener added by me firing when you close the modal ?

Comment: I did write the code you mentioned and yes it is firing but the outcome isn't what I wanted.